# Reinstalling package after manually removing directory

Tags: apt-get

I was trying to properly configure nginx, but after many modifications I messed up so much that I decided to remove the package with `sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx` - but the nginx directory was still there with all the config files, so I removed it manually. Right now when I'm trying to install it it doesn't create nginx directory at all. I was trying to create it by myself and then install, but it didn't change anything.

So right now I can't install properly nginx. Is there any command which will install all over again? ( I was trying also with reinstall - didn't help either )

`dpkg -L nginx-common` OUTPUT:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common/copyright
/usr/share/nginx
/usr/share/nginx/html
/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html
/var
/var/log
/var/log/nginx
/var/lib
/var/lib/nginx
/run
/etc
/etc/ufw
/etc/ufw/applications.d
/etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx
/etc/logrotate.d
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
/etc/nginx
/etc/nginx/sites-available
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
/etc/nginx/conf.d
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/etc/nginx/win-utf
/etc/nginx/koi-utf
/etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules
/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
/etc/nginx/scgi_params
/etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
/etc/nginx/mime.types
/etc/nginx/naxsi-ui.conf.1.4.1
/etc/nginx/koi-win
/etc/nginx/proxy_params
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/default
/etc/default/nginx
/lib
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common/CHANGES.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

The `nginx` package is actually just a metapackage that doesn't have any files in it. Try reinstalling `nginx-common` and `nginx-full`.

This would also explain why your `--purge` didn't delete the configs.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. Although it created SOME config files in nginx directory, but when I try to start it ( sudo service nginx start ) it shows that there is no `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' file.

Comment: With nginx-full still same error :P no `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' file

Comment: Could you post the output of `dpkg -L nginx-common`?

Comment: I've edited my question - there is output.

Comment: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is in the package... Try purge removing all nginx related packages and reinstalling again.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, try the instructions here ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files) for nginx-common.

Comment: damn, none of those things works :/ I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Worst case scenario you could extract the nginx-common package and get the config from there.

Comment: The problem is that those packages even after removing and installing again does not create all the neccessary directories and files, not only this config file.

Comment: The process above should work, but since it doesn't seem to be, download the package with `aptitude download nginx-common`, install `ar` by installing the binutils package, extract the debian archive with `ar vx nginx-common*`, and extract the data archive with `tar -xf data.tar.xz`. There will be an etc/nginx directory. Copy any missing files from there.